# Validar sólo ingreso de números en C++

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Necesito que sólo me acepte números y no letras.

¿Cómo se puede hacer esa validación? ¿Cómo hacer una función `esDigito`?

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi*/
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double ConvierteANumero(char valor[3])
{   int n;
    n = atoi(valor); 
    return n; 
}
int main ()
{
    char valor[3];
    int n,m=10;
    cout<< ("Ingrese edad: ");
    cin>>valor;
    n=ConvierteANumero(valor);
    m=m+n;
    cout<< "Edad antigua:"<<n<<"\nEdad nueva  :"<<m;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C++ dispones del método `isdigit` para verificar si un caracter determinado es un número o no:

```
#include <cctype>

std::cout << std::isdigit('f'); // 0
std::cout << std::isdigit('5'); // 1
```

Con esta función, implementar una verificación es trivial:

```
bool EsUnNumero(const char* cadena)
{
  for( ; *cadena; ++cadena )
  {
    // En cuanto un caracter no sea numérico
    if( !std::isdigit(*cadena) )
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Claro que también puedes optar por hacer el chequeo a mano. Básicamente se trata de verificar que cada caracter que compone el número se encuentra entre el caracter '0' y el caracter '9'. Si echas un vistazo a una tabla ASCII verás que el caracter '0' está en un índice menor que el caracter '9', luego un carácter será numérico si su valor es mayor o igual a '0' y menor o igual a '9'.

Como de lo que se trata es de verificar si una secuencia es numérica o no podemos simplificar el argumento diciendo que una secuencia **no será numérica** si al menos un carácter no es numérico o, dicho con código:

```
bool EsUnNumero(const char* cadena)
{
  for( ; *cadena; ++cadena )
  {
    // En cuanto un caracter no sea numérico
    if( '0' > *cadena || '9' < *cadena )
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias de sirvió de mucho ..!

Comment: también tiene este programa usando climits en c++. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67636/is-it-friday-yet/183496#183496

Answer (score 3):

Ahi te va un programa que valida la entrada, pero es un ejemplo con enteros solamente.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

string s;

bool isOk(string x) {

    while(s.size() > 1 && x[0] == ' ')
        x.erase(x.begin());

    int ini = x[0] == '-';

    for(int i=ini;i<x.size();i++)
        if('0' <= x[i] && x[i] <= '9')
            continue;
        else
            return false;

    return true;

}

int toNumber(string x) {

    while(s.size() > 1 && x[0] == ' ')
        x.erase(x.begin());

    int ini = x[0] == '-', res = 0;

    for(int i=ini;i<x.size();i++) {
        res *= 10;
        res += x[i] - '0';
    }

    return ini?-res:res;

}

int main() {

    cin >> s;

    if(isOk(s))
        cout << "El numero leido es " << toNumber(s) << endl;
    else
        cout << "Formato no valido" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```