# Validar entrada de datos FLOAT

Tags: c++, conversión-de-tipos, float

Necesito que el programa solo acepte números decimales. El que hice está bien, solo acepta decimales, pero si se ingresa por ejemplo `-23.45jdhsdj`. Los números si los guarda, aunque ignora las letras y no debería ser así.
Debería rechazar un número que contenga letra en cualquier parte del mismo.

Aquí les dejo lo que he logrado hasta el momento:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
bool funciondecimal(string);
int main()
{
string numero;
bool repite=true;
do{
  cout<<"Dijite el numero: ";
  cin>>numero;

   if(!funciondecimal(numero)){
    cout<<"tiene punto decimal"<<endl;
    repite=false;
   }else{
    cout<<"No tiene punto decimal"<<endl;
   }
}while(repite);
return 0;
}
bool funciondecimal(string numero){
  bool resp= true;
   for(int contador=1;contador<=numero.size();contador++){
    if(numero[contador-1]=='.'|| numero[contador-1]==','){
            resp=false;
            break;
    }
}
return resp;
}
```

PD: me pusieron la pregunta como duplicada, pero la que existe actualmente y tiene solucion es para enteros y esta la necesito solo para FLOAT, gracias
[Aqui la solucion para enteros en Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30801/validar-s%C3%B3lo-ingreso-de-n%C3%BAmeros-en-c)

Aqui les dejo la ultima mejora que le hice: ya no permite letras pero sigue permitiendo caracteres (!@#$%^&*?<+), si alguien tiene una idea de como lo soluciono seria genial, gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
bool funciondecimal(string);
int main()
{
string numero;
bool repite=true;
do{
cout<<"Dijite el numero: ";
cin>>numero;

if(funciondecimal(numero)){
    cout<<"tiene punto decimal"<<endl;
    repite=false;
}else{
    cout<<"No tiene punto decimal"<<endl;
}
}while(repite);
return 0;
}
bool funciondecimal(string numero){
bool resp= false;
 for(int contador=1;contador<=numero.size();contador++){
    if((numero[contador-1]=='-'|| numero[contador-1]=='+')  &&  (numero[contador]==','|| numero[contador]=='.')){
            resp=true;
            break;
    }
 }
 for (int contador2=1;contador2<=numero.size();contador2++){
        if((numero[contador2]>='0' && numero[contador2]<='9') &&   (numero[contador2]==','|| numero[contador2]=='.')){
            resp=true;
        }
 }
 for(int contador3=1;contador3<=numero.size();contador3++){
        if(numero[contador3-1]==','|| numero[contador3-1]=='.'){
            resp=true;
        }
 }
 for(int contador4=1;contador4<=numero.size();contador4++){
        for(int letra='a';letra<='z';letra++){
                if(numero[contador4-1]==letra){
                  resp=false;
                  break;
                }
        }
        for(int letra2='A';letra2<='Z';letra2++){
            if(numero[contador4-1]==letra2){
               resp=false;
               break;
               }
        }
   // if(numero[contador4-1]=='a'){
     //   resp=false;
       // break;
    //}
 }
return resp;
}
```

Comment: Marqué la pregunta como duplicada porque es en efecto, un duplicado: en ambas preguntas estáis almacenando un número en una cadena de caracteres y en ambas preguntas queréis comprobar que lo que se ha leído es un número. Que sea coma flotante o entero es simplemente una variante de la misma pregunta. Comprueba que hayas leído los caracteres del 0 al 9 e incluye en la comprobación el separador decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde C++11 tienes a tu disposición la función [`std::stof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), que hace justamente lo que buscas:

```
bool EsFloat(std::string const& numero)
{
  bool toReturn = false;

  try
  {
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    std::stof(numero,&pos);

    // Verificamos que se ha procesado todo el contenido de numero 
    toReturn = ( pos == numero.length() );
  }

  catch(std::exception const&)
  {
    // 1234e1000 -> std::out_of_range      
    // HOLA      -> std::invalid_argument
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

Si nos remontamos a estándares anteriores, encontramos una versión un tanto más tosca llamada [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) (en vez de trabajar con `std::string` usa `char*` y, además, esta función no lanza excepciones):

```
#include <cmath> 
bool EsFloat(std::string const& numero)
{
  bool toReturn = false;

  char* pos = 0;
  float result = std::strtof(numero.c_str(),&pos);

  // Verificamos que se ha procesado todo el contenido de numero  
  toReturn = (pos == &numero[numero.length()] && result);

  // Y comprobamos además que el numero resultante es valido
  toReturn &= (result != std::HUGE_VAL);

  return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, lamentablemente ninguno de los codigos me funciona ambos me tiran varios tipos de errores. ya he mejorado un poco mas mi codigo mejorado, pero aun me toma caracteres (@#$%^&*?><).

Comment: @AliRash si te salen errores es porque no has añadido los includes correspondientes. Un ejemplo del código funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7PDGG6sCVTzxVeWv)

Comment: **|13|error: 'strtof' is not a member of 'std'|** entre otros errores

Comment: @AliRash como puedes ver en el ejemplo que te he puesto, el código compila. Si te da errores revisa la versión de tu compilador y las librerías que incluyes

Comment: muchas gracias bro, supongo que si es un problema de mi compilador y como soy nuevo en esto se me complica mucho entender el tipo de errores, te califique como respuesta porque el que acabas de poner si compila aunque en mi codeblocks no, de igual manera ya logre terminarlo por mi cuenta, añadiendo un ciclo for siguiendo el orden de los caracteres ASCII, muchas gracias de nuevo